# Change Apache listen on localhost

Tags: apache, nginx, localhost, webserver

I've installed Nginx to my ubuntu machine. And by default, as I understood it should listen on port `80` and should be available by `localhost` in the browser address bar, but I mentioned that this port already occupied by Apache.

[image]

It returns me this page. My question is, how can I change this behavior and make Nginx listen on the `localhost`? What I've tried is to delete Apache, was thinking it will help, but it didn't.

I've used this command :

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

What I've got in response is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `What I've tried is to delete Apache, was thinking it will help, but it didn't.` Please edit your question, show exactly what you did, and what happened.  Your understanding is correct - nginx will by default listen on port 80, but if Apache was already installed and running, *it* is already listening on port 80 and blocking nginx. The solution is to shutdown Apache, and remove it, so it does not restart on next boot.

Comment: check my addition pls, if it will help you

Comment: ok, I've restarted then my machine, and cleared cache and have got nginx forbidden page, it is better

Comment: Bingo! You've solved this problem. Now to solve the next step ... :-)